# Как на css flexbox реализовать такую структуру из трех блоков?

Tags: css, вёрстка, flexbox

```
|         |......................... top navigation
|  LOGO   | —————————————---------------------------
|         |..................slogan...............
```

Это на десктопе, а на мобильном все проще

```
| LOGO | 
|slogan|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ @Yuri доработан (удалены лишние стили) и добавлена мобильная версия.

```css
.header {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.logo {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.svg?v=01c1db151660),none;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}

.main {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Занимать оставшееся пространство */
  flex: 1;
}

.nav {
  display: flex;
  padding: 5px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  width: 100%;
}

.nav a {
  margin-right: 10px;
  color: #fff;
}

.slogan {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
   .header {
     flex-direction: column;
   }
   
   .logo {
     /* отцентрировать картинку */
     margin: 0 auto;
   }
   
   .nav {
     display: none;
   }
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="nav">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">Пункт 1</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">Пункт 2</a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0);">Пункт 3</a>
    </div>
    <div class="slogan">Сто раз отмерь</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.header {display:flex;background-color:#474747;width:100%;height:60px}
.logo {
  background-image: url(https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/ru/img/sprites.svg?v=01c1db151660),none;
  background-position: top left;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
}
.main {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.nav {display: flex;padding:5px; justify-content: flex-end; width: 100%}
.nav a {display: block;margin-right:10px;color: white;}
.slogan {color:white;padding:5px;text-align:center;}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <div class="logo"></div>
  <div class="main">
    <div class="nav"><a href="">Пункт 1</a><a href="">Пункт 2</a><a href="">Пункт 3</a></div>
    <div class="slogan">Сто раз отмерь</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А на мобильные реализовываете с помощью `@media`

Comment: я такой вариант предполагал.  хотелось обойтись без .main

Comment: @user3529191, оно все блоки, тогда, в столбец или строку выставит

Answer (score 0):

Навигация и слоган в отдельный контейнер, если взять, то возможен такой вариант

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 2px;
}
.fb__1-header {
  display: flex;
}
.fb__1_2-logo {
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.fb__1_3-header__menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
.fb__3_4-nav {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
.fb__3_5-slogan {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fb fb__1-header">
  <div class="fb fb__1_2-logo">
    logo
  </div>
  <div class="fb fb__1_3-header__menu">
    <div class="fb fb__3_4-nav">
      nav

    </div>
    <div class="fb fb__3_5-slogan">
      slogan

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

А для мобильного, что-то наподобие

```css
div {
  border: solid 1px black;
  padding: 2px;  
}

.fb__1-header {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.fb__1_2-logo {
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.fb__1_3-header__menu {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-self: flex-start;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.fb__3_4-slogan {
  align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="fb fb__1-header">
  <div class="fb fb__1_2-logo">
    logo
  </div>
  <div class="fb fb__1_3-header__menu">
    <div class="fb fb__3_4-slogan">
      slogan

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```